# Why width 100% not work with flex-direction: row?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two parts inside main:

1. Types of products(phones, laptops)
2. Brands and products

And to put them in this order I use `display: flex; flex-direction: row`. But when I start to do devices rows I set `width: 100%` to main, `display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100%;` to device container and `width: 25%` to every device. But it just didn't stretch.

[image: problem showcase]

But when I removed `display: flex; flex-direction: row` and added `display: grid; grid-template-column` in main all start warking. I understand that problem solved, but I don't understand why it didn't work with flex.

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Demianeen/8somt3fh/17/)

Comment: Flexbox child elements need to be allowed to grow explicitly with `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1`. With `flex-direction: row` they will grow to fill the parent space horizontally, with `flex-direction: column` they will grow to fill the parent space vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add flex-grow: 1 to the child elements of the wrapper. See snippet below.

```css
.flexed > div {
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexed" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;">
  <ul>
    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>
    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>

    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>

    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>

    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>

    <li style="cursor: pointer">type</li>

  </ul>
  <div>
    <div>
      <ul style=" display: flex; flex-direction: row; list-style: none">
        <li style=" background: white; color: black; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; ">brand</li>
        <li style=" background: white; color: black; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; ">brand</li>
        <li style=" background: white; color: black; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; ">brand</li>
        <li style=" background: white; color: black; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; ">brand</li>
        <li style=" background: white; color: black; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; ">brand</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div style=" display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; gap: 15px; padding-left: 40px; width: 100%; ">
      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>
      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>

      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>

      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>

      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>

      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>

      <div style=" cursor: pointer; margin: 15px; border: 2px solid black; width: 25%; ">device</div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```